# How to speedup php soap client

Tags: php, soap

I'm using a web service to send SMS in PHP. The code in like below:

```
$options = array(
'login' => 'yourusername',
'password' => 'yourpassword'
);
$client = new SoapClient('http://sms.hostiran.net/webservice/?WSDL', $options);
try
{
    $messageId = $client->send(destination mobile number, 'test sms');
    sleep(3);
    print ($client->deliveryStatus($messageId));
    var_dump($client->accountInfo());
}
catch (SoapFault $sf)
{
    print $sf->faultcode."\n";
    print $sf->faultstring."\n";
}
```

The problem is that when i run this code on a WAMP server, it runs rapidly.But when i use this code in an ubuntu server, the speed of running this code is very low.
Is there any configuration in php.ini to solve this problem ?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes. Even when i use this code, the result is the same as before:                                                           'login' => smsusername,
'password' => smspassword
);
$client = new SoapClient('http://sms.hostiran.net/webservice/?WSDL', $options);
$client->send($mobile, $message);

Comment: Makes sense, `hostiran.net` takes around 5 seconds for me to load in my browser. Your WAMP and Ubuntu are at different locations.

Comment: No. they are both in the same network with same bandwidth.

Comment: This code is recommended by hostiran.net. i did not make any changes to it.

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to remove sleep(3). That makes it take an extra 3 seconds.

Second, it looks like the sms provider is in Iran so it'd be best for you to get a web server in Iran.

As far as I know there is no reason why a Ubuntu server would be slower at SOAP than a Windows server

If you want to try and speed up the webpage what you should do is instead of running the SOAP request on page load you save the request to a database and then have a cron that runs every few minutes, pulls the requests out of the database, and makes the request.